# Why can't I return the form with cond as I can with if-else?

Tags: scheme, racket, control-flow

Inspired by the syntax of `if` from the exercise 1.4 [from SICP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sicp+scheme),
I tried to code something similar but with `cond`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env racket
#lang racket/base

(define (b x) (display (bytes-append #"\033[1m" (string->bytes/utf-8 x) #"\33[m")))
(define (i x) (display (bytes-append #"\33[3m" (string->bytes/utf-8 x) #"\33[m")))
#|
(define (formatted-printer s)
  ((if (equal? s "You have to be bold to do it.\n") b i) s)); Works fine, preferred as it is concise. Do the same with cond!!!
(define (formatted-printer s)
  (if (equal? s "You have to be bold to do it.\n") 
    (b s)
    (i s))); Works fine, too verbose, though.|#

#|
(define (formatted-printer s); Works fine
  (cond 
    ((equal? s "You have to be bold to do it.\n") (b s))
    ((equal? s "You have to be Italian in order to eat pasta.\n") (i s))
    ))
|#
(define (formatted-printer s)
  ((cond 
    ((equal? s "You have to be bold to do it.\n") b)
    ((equal? s "You have to be Italian in order to eat pasta.\n") i)
      s)));Does not work: cond: bad syntax (clause is not a test-value pair) 


    
(formatted-printer "You have to be bold to do it.\n")
(formatted-printer "You have to be Italian in order to eat pasta.\n")
```

Sadly, when I try to apply double parentheses around `cond`, as it did the trick around `if`, I get:

```
cond: bad syntax (clause is not a test-value pair)
  at: s
  in: (cond ((equal? s "You have to be bold to do it.\n") b) ((equal? s "You have to be Italian in order to eat pasta.\n") i) s)
  location...:
```

The comments hint what I am aiming at.
Is it at all doable to select with `cond` only the operator like it is with `if`?

Comment: Parentheses: `...to eat pasta.\n") i)` should be `...to eat pasta.\n") i))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `if` version you are ending the `if` form aplying the result with `s` as the operand. In the `cond` version you don't. It should  be like this:

```
(define (formatted-printer s)
  ((cond 
    ((equal? s "You have to be bold to do it.\n") b)
    ((equal? s "You have to be Italian in order to eat pasta.\n") i)
    (else (error "no matching string for formatted-printer")))
   s))
```

Notice the `else`. If you don't have that you can in the future end up with a weird application: not a procedure for `#<void>` since if none of the strings match and you don't have an `else` Racket will use its undefined value as the result and that can not be called as a procedure.

You can even make it more clear:

```
(define (formatted-printer s)
  (define formatter
    (cond 
      ((equal? s "You have to be bold to do it.\n") b)
      ((equal? s "You have to be Italian in order to eat pasta.\n") i)
      (else (error "no matching string for formatted-printer"))))
  (formatter s))
```

Since you're using Racket and probably DrRacket you can even debug this much easier with adding a breakpoint at `(formatter s)` to investigate the result of what `formatter` was set to.